# Bootstrap3 Float Button Bottom of Panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3:
I'm trying to float a button center halfway outside the panel-footer. But the whole layout is responsive so I need to have it when the screen size is resized or smaller it is still correct. 
I created a bootply with my attempt that is close but doesn't stay when the screen is resized. 
Thanks,
Nate

[Bootply Trial](http://www.bootply.com/113993)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to get? http://www.bootply.com/114327

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

.bottom-btn {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -17px; /* half of the button height */
    margin-left: -77px; /* half of the button width */
    /* instead of bottom and margin-left, you can use translateX as well. */
}
```

play with css `position` property and use `margin` to get exact position. see the comments for the `.bottom-btn` class.

Comment: Thank You! Works perfect, I knew it had to be simple.

Comment: you're welcome. if this answer solved ur issue, plz upvote and accept the answer.